# How do I stop Billing Address being set as shipping by default?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I just want the **My billing and shipping address are the same** checkbox to be unchecked by default and let the customer see the form to enter a new billing address.

I think the answer lies within this file:
`Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/billing-address.js`

But I've tried an awful lot of things with no success.

I need to set **isAddressSameAsShipping** to false?

I mean I can just uncheck it using JavaScript, but that just seems like cheating..

Thanks

Comment: You can do it using javascript, if its working using js no problem for form

Answer (score 4):

Override `..vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/transparent.js` and add this code :

```
var paymentMethodId = jQuery(".payment-methods input[type='radio']:checked").attr('id');

jQuery("#billing-address-same-as-shipping-"+paymentMethodId).trigger('click');
jQuery(".payment-method").find('select[name="billing_address_id"]  option:last-child').attr('selected','selected');
jQuery(".payment-method").find('.billing-address-form').show();
```

Override `../magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-billing-address.js`:
(Add code)

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".payment-method",function(){
         console.log(   jQuery(this).find('input[name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"]').is(":checked") );             
         console.log(jQuery(this).find('select[name="billing_address_id"]  option:last-child'));
         jQuery(this).find('input[name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"]').trigger('click');
         jQuery(this).find('select[name="billing_address_id"]  option:last-child').attr('selected','selected');
         jQuery(this).find('.billing-address-form').show();
    })
```

Comment: Rather dissappointing answer. The question clearly stated not to use Javascript.

Comment: You can use as alternative solution , Its not the way to down-vote any answer @leedch

Answer (score 1):

*I am copy/pasting my answer from [Magento 2 : Uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in checkout payment page based on shipping method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160020/magento-2-uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-in-che)*

Disclaimer: I am an author of an article at the end of this answer.

**Magento best practices way.**

1. Create a simple [Magento 2 extension](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/).
2. Create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with the content:

   ```
   var config = {
    map: {
    '*': {
      'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': 'Vendor_Module/js/checkout-data-resolver',
      'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Vendor_Module/js/shipping-save-processor/default'
     }
   }};
   ```
3. Copy file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js`.
4. Edit file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js` and comment out code around line 231:

   ```
       applyBillingAddress: function () {
           var shippingAddress;

           if (quote.billingAddress()) {
               selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

               return;
           }
           shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

           /*if (shippingAddress &&
               shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
               (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
           ) {
               selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
           }*/
       }
   };
   ```
5. Copy file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js`.
6. In `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js` comment out code around line 34:

   ```
   saveShippingInformation: function () {
   var payload;

   /*if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
       selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
   }*/

   payload = {
   ```
7. Delete folder pub/static/frontend:

   ```
    rm -rf pub/static/frontend
   ```
8. Regenerate static content:

   ```
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
9. Clear magento cache and you are all set.

**Dirty way**

Instead of steps 1 through 6 simply edit the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` and comment out code around line 231 as in step 4 and edit the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` and comment code code around line 34 as in step 6.

Repeat steps 7,8,9.

Originally published as https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-set-billing-shipping-address-unchecked-default-checkout

Answer (score 0):

I have traced the code that sets the default value for the SameAsBilling attribute in the `Quote\Address` model.

The  `$address->setSameAsBilling(1)` is called in `Quote\Address::_populateBeforeSaveData()` which in turn is called in `Quote\Address::beforeSave()`

The below solution works for the backend sale, where the order form comes with the selected checkbox, which makes the data input very cumbersome, since after each field is populated, theres a loading period for syncing the fields.

I have created a Plugin for the Quote\Address, as follows:

**Vendor\Package\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
    <plugin name="cinch_ticketsale_plugin_quote_address"
        type="Vendor\Package\Plugin\QuoteAdress"
        sortOrder="10"
        disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

**Vendor\Package\Plugin\QuoteAdress**

```
namespace Vendor\Package\Plugin;

class QuoteAdress
{
    protected $_forceNotSameAsBilling = null;

    public function aroundBeforeSave($subject, $proceed)
    {
        if (!$subject->getId()) {
            $this->_forceNotSameAsBilling = true;
        }

        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $this->_forceNotSameAsBilling = false;

        return $returnValue;
    }

    public function aroundSetSameAsBilling($subject, $proceed, $sameAsBilling) {
        if ($this->_forceNotSameAsBilling) $sameAsBilling = 0;

        return $proceed($sameAsBilling);
    }
}
```