# Magento 2 : Uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in checkout payment page based on shipping method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am working on magento 2.1.3.
I want to uncheck My billing and shipping address are the same checkbox in checkout payment page based on shipping method.

If shipping method is Store Pickup i want to uncheck checkbox by default.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I also want the same, the checkbox to be unchecked on page load.

Comment: not yet .... :(

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there anyone who found the solution for same.

Comment: @SudheeshKSurendran, found any solution?

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I am an author of an article at the end of this answer.

**Magento best practices way.**

1. Create a simple [Magento 2 extension](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/).
2. Create a file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with the content:

   ```
   var config = {
    map: {
    '*': {
      'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': 'Vendor_Module/js/checkout-data-resolver',
      'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Vendor_Module/js/shipping-save-processor/default'
     }
   }};
   ```
3. Copy file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js`.
4. Edit file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-data-resolver.js` and comment out code around line 231:

   ```
       applyBillingAddress: function () {
           var shippingAddress;

           if (quote.billingAddress()) {
               selectBillingAddress(quote.billingAddress());

               return;
           }
           shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

           /*if (shippingAddress &&
               shippingAddress.canUseForBilling() &&
               (shippingAddress.isDefaultShipping() || !quote.isVirtual())
           ) {
               selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
           }*/
       }
   };
   ```
5. Copy file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js`.
6. In `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-save-processor/default.js` comment out code around line 34:

   ```
   saveShippingInformation: function () {
   var payload;

   /*if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
       selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
   }*/

   payload = {
   ```
7. Delete folder pub/static/frontend:

   ```
    rm -rf pub/static/frontend
   ```
8. Regenerate static content:

   ```
    php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
   ```
9. Clear magento cache and you are all set.

**Dirty way**

Instead of steps 1 through 6 simply edit the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/checkout-data-resolver.js` and comment out code around line 231 as in step 4 and edit the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js` and comment code code around line 34 as in step 6.

Repeat steps 7,8,9.

Originally published as https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-set-billing-shipping-address-unchecked-default-checkout

Comment: Unable to make it work in 2.2.3.  Anyway you can look in to it? Thank you

Comment: Does not work on 2.1.12

Comment: the question is need to uncheck based on the shipping method

Comment: How Can we get Shipping Method using this?

Answer (score 7):

**Just copy this file in your theme :** vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js

Checkbox on the payment section depends on this js variable '**isAddressSameAsShipping**' which is define in above file.

```
  this._super()
                .observe({
                    selectedAddress: null,
                    isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                    isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                    isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                    saveInAddressBook: 1
                });
```

By default, the variable is false, but this function change the value of this variable from false to true, if quote is not Virtual:

```
  quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
            if (quote.isVirtual()) {
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
            } else {
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(
                    newAddress != null &&
                    newAddress.getCacheKey() == quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey()  //return true
                );
            }

            if (newAddress != null && newAddress.saveInAddressBook !== undefined) {
                this.saveInAddressBook(newAddress.saveInAddressBook);
            } else {
                this.saveInAddressBook(1);
            }
            this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
        }, this);
```

Just change above **'initObservable'** function like following:

```
    initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .observe({
                selectedAddress: null,
                isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                saveInAddressBook: 1
            });
        quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
            if (quote.isVirtual()) {
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
            } 
            if (newAddress != null && newAddress.saveInAddressBook !== undefined) {
                this.saveInAddressBook(newAddress.saveInAddressBook);
            } else {
                this.saveInAddressBook(1);
            }
            this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code , how it is different then default code ?

Comment: You need to add this just start of function:              this._super()
                .observe({
                    selectedAddress: null,
                    isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                    isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                    isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                    saveInAddressBook: 1
                });

Comment: do i need to add this "this._super()
                .observe({
                    selectedAddress: null,
                    isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                    isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                    isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                    saveInAddressBook: 1
                });" code seperately in "initialize: function "  function?

Comment: Yes add this in initObservable/ initialize function

Comment: While changing shipping address, the checkbox "billing address same as shipping" gets ticked , how to fix that ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: after copying this obsevable function checkbox unchecked but billing form was not displaying.

Comment: how can we get shipping method in this?