# (issue) Setting custom shipping address in "new-customer-address.js " sets same address for both billing and shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I m trying to set custom shipping address in

**"new-customer-address.js"**

```
Magento_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address.js
```

file but it **sets same address for shipping and billing**.

how can i **set shipping address** only ?

Comment: Have you tried this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160020/magento-2-uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-in-che/206092#206092

Comment: Let me try it now

Comment: Error - The shipping address is missing. Set the address and try again.

Comment: i have added that code into the function  and now , reload of address is stopped while adding new billing address , any reason ?

Comment: There is issue.

Comment: provide  the full function after adding code

Comment: initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .observe({
                selectedAddress: null,
                isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                saveInAddressBook: 1
            });

Comment: quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
            if (quote.isVirtual()) {
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
            } 
            
            if (newAddress != null && newAddress.saveInAddressBook !== undefined) {
                this.saveInAddressBook(newAddress.saveInAddressBook);
            } else {
                this.saveInAddressBook(1);
            }
            this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }

Comment: I am not seeing any updated code in this function.

Comment: I can see there is one update "addressOptions.length === 1" and one else condition is removed  & i 've also removed "shippingRatesValidator.initFields(this.get('name') + '.form-fields');" from "initialize: function () " function

Comment: Let me know what's left. Appreciate your help :)