How can I change on magento 2.4.7 checkout page the default "isAddressSameAsShipping" checkbox to be uncheck by default?
How can I change on magento 2.4.7 checkout page the default "isAddressSameAsShipping" checkbox to be uncheck by default?


Check my detailed answer in a similar post at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361932/uncheck-my-billing-and-shipping-address-are-the-same-checkbox-by-default

It doesn't work properly, I want to be uncheck by default, but it should work the same way , by default, I want to be close the form

You can change this behavior by modifying the checkout module.
Override the Checkout JavaScript Component
You need to override the JavaScript component that controls the checkbox behavior.
Create the JavaScript file:
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/checkout.js
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data'
], function (Component, checkoutData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // Set the default state of the 'isAddressSameAsShipping' checkbox to unchecked
            var shippingAddressSameAsBilling = checkoutData.get('isAddressSameAsShipping');
            if (typeof shippingAddressSameAsBilling !== 'undefined') {
                checkoutData.set('isAddressSameAsShipping', false);
            }
        }
    });
});

Create the requirejs-config.js file to override the default JavaScript:
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/checkout': 'Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/checkout'
        }
    }
};

